# Is K-Means ++ is the best method to initialize centroids?

Tags: clustering

I recently came across different initialization strategies like random, parition and kmeans ++. In many places it is mentioned K-means++ has better initiailization strategy. Is it true? or Is there better methods ?

Comment: HI yash, are you interested in methods which are more efficient or which lead to "better" clusters?

Comment: Since I work on big data a lot, I would prefer a efficient one. but feel free to suggest your thoughts on both